# How to prevent ajax from confirming on success content already inside a div

Tags: java, html, jquery, ajax

How to prevent ajax from confirming on success content already in  in this case in `$('.Mydiv').Append(data);`

```
$(document).ready(function (ajaxCall) {

    var offset = 0;
    var limit = offset + 4;
    var cats_in_home = '<?php echo $myCat ?>';
    var request_in_progress = false;

    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'getActivity.php',
        data: {
            'offset': offset,
            'limit': limit,
            'cats_in_home': cats_in_home
        },

        success: function (data) {
            $('.get_communication_with_div_class').html(data);
        }
    });

    $('.MySeconddiv').onclick(function () {

        if (request_in_progress) {
            return;
        }

        request_in_progress = true;

        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: 'getActivity.php',
            data: {
                'offset': offset += 6,
                'limit': limit,
                'cats_in_home': cats_in_home
            },

            success: function (data) {
                $('.Mydiv').append(data);
                request_in_progress = false;
            }
        });
    });
});
```

the problem is when i click the MySeconddiv  tag its accept duplicates,
plese help
i cant find way to find a solution
i cant find way to find a solution

Comment: How many times can `MySeconddiv` be clicked? If the objective is to allow users to click it only once per `.MySeconddiv`, you can use the `one` method instead. For example, `$('.MySeconddiv').one('click', function ()`.

Comment: Until the information in the database runs out, because it loads six results per click, but I do not need duplicate results

Comment: I just realized you are using `onclick`, it should by `click` in jQuery, e.g. `$('.MySeconddiv').click(`. As for other parts of your code, they seem to be ok.

Comment: Also, a few suggestions I would like to make if you're new into programming/HTML/JS/jQuery. (1) If you're going to have an element which will be unique throughout the HTML, provide it an `id` and reference it using the `id` instead of class. (2) If the purpose of an element is to accept user's input, use the appropriate element as much as possible. For e.g., since `MySeconddiv` is a click input, it should ideally be an anchor (`a`) tag.

Comment: Do check if you're getting the appropriate values of `offset` and `limit` when you're getting the values.

Comment: Exactly the same ajax option in scroll works fine, the thing here is that the sql function is complex and provides the end result except that there are duplicates, and I thought that here in the ajax function I can solve the problem, something like if (data == "same_as_divone) {} else {continue}  "